# Remove duplicate rows in R

Tags: r

I have this code that remove duplicate rows in 2 columns but when i checked the number of rows after running the code i am getting the same number of rows. What am i doing wrong?

```
library(readxl)
library("dplyr")
library("tidyverse")
Test_1 <- read_excel("SGWS/Test 1.xlsx")
View(Test_1)
test_2<- read_excel("SGWS/Test 2.xlsx")
View(test_2)

save(Test_1, file = "Test_1.Rdata")
save(test_2, file = "Test_2.Rdata")

names(Test_1)[names(Test_1)=="Brand Name Final"] <- "Brand"


sort.Test_new <- with(Test_1,  Test_1[order(Brand,code) , ])
sort.Test_md <- with(test_2,  test_2[order(Brand, `State Product Code` ) , ])
nrow(sort.Test_new)
nrow(sort.Test_md)
```

#See how many rows are duplicated on Brand and code and remove them

```
sort.Test_new[!duplicated(sort.Test_new$Brand,sort.Test_new$code), ]
sort.Test_new %>% distinct(code, Brand, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

##See how many rows are duplicated on Brand and State product code and remove them

```
sort.Test_md[!duplicated(sort.Test_new$Brand,sort.Test_md$`State Product Code`), ]
sort.Test_md %>% distinct(Brand, `State Product Code`, .keep_all = TRUE)

Assignment <-merge (x=sort.Test_md, y=sort.Test_new, by ="Brand", all.x=TRUE)



AssignmentFinal<- subset(Assignment, Flag=="MD")

nrow(AssignmentFinal)
```

Comment: Your one line of code using `duplicated` is not being saved anywhere, so the duplicate-removal is being ignored. (Same with `distinct`.)

Comment: If you want much more help, it's very difficult to do much without sample data, please provide a small, representative sample of data (no more than necessary columns/rows, please), and provide the output of `dput` on that sample. Thanks!

Comment: i am still getting the same number of rows after i saved it. Whats the code if you want to remove the duplicated based on 2 columns which are brand and code. Is it that? sort.Test_new[!duplicated(sort.Test_new$Brand,sort.Test_new$code), ]
sort.Test_new %>% distinct(code, Brand, .keep_all = TRUE) @r2evans

Comment: (1) Do you ever `sort.Test_new <- sort.Test_new[!duplicated(...),]`? (2) *Still* having a hard time with salient suggestions without sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of a way to remove duplicate rows either based on certain columns or on the entire row.

```
#Creating fake data with duplicates
Brand<-c("A","B","C","A")
Code<-c(1,2,3,1)
X<-c(10,20,30,40)
df<-data.frame(Brand,Code,X)

#See what row numbers are duplicates
which(duplicated(df[,c("Brand","Code")]))

#Create new dataframe excluding row numbers that are duplicates in two columns
df1<-df[-which(duplicated(df[,c("Brand","Code")])),]

#If the entire row should be duplicated
df1<-df[-which(duplicated(df[,])),]
#notice this doesn't do anything because column X has no duplicates
```